# How to navigate BIRT child report from parent report in another iframe of HTML page

Tags: iframe, xhtml, birt

I have created master child report. In master report, I have made one of the column as hyperlink which is pointing to child report through drill through. Now for integrating this report in my web project, I am using iframe. In iframe src, I am giving URL of my uploaded report on server.

In iframe, parent report appears properly with my xhtml page. But for now I want is that after clicking on the hyperlink of parent report, child report is getting opened in new window. And my requirement is like the child window needs to be opened in another xhtml's iframe src. Please anyone help.

Comment: I worked on it. Its done.